# jQuery show and hide PHP generated content

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am a total jQuery noob. But I need to use it for a script in combination with PHP. The idea is that people can add a new lawyer on the backend and that a button and content are added to the page. On the site you would then be able to cycle through the lawyers by using the buttons as in the example below.

http://strak-design.com/varlaw/team

Here is the site in question and how I would like it to work. Right now it's simply smoke and mirrors for my clients and if I add and remove lawyers dynamically it obviously breaks.

Here's my HTML/PHP. Any ideas? In don't even know where to start...

```
<?php foreach ($team as $lawyer) { ?>
<div id="<?php echo $lawyer->id?>_button" class="lawyer_title_small title-<?php echo $lawyer->title_colour;?>">
    <h2><?php echo $lawyer->name?></h2>
</div>
<?php }?>

<?php foreach ($team as $lawyer) { ?>
<div id="<?php echo $lawyer->id;?>" class="team_info">
    <div class="team_info_left">
        <img src="img/team/<?php echo $lawyer->picture;?>"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="color: #9e0039;">TEL:</th>
                <th><?php echo $lawyer->tel;?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="color: #9e0039;">GSM:</th>
                <th><?php echo $lawyer->gsm;?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="color: #9e0039;">MAIL:</th>
                <th style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo $lawyer->mail;?></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="team_info_right">
        <h4>OVER <?php echo $lawyer->name;?></h4>
        <?php echo $lawyer->about;?>
        <h4>VOORKEURKENNIS:</h4>
        <?php echo $lawyer->knowledge;?>
    </div>

</div>
<?php }?>
```

If it isn't clear, I'll try to explain further. Thanks a lot!

Comment: jquery has no knowledge or awareness of PHP's existence, nor should it. Doesn't matter WHERE your html comes from, it's all just html to jquery. if you want jquery to handle something php generated, then your php code has to generate somethign in a structure/format that jquery will accept (e.g. appropriate tag structure and/or dom ID's).

Comment: Can you put some meat on the statement "people can add a new lawyer on the backend" please? Presumably these people are administrators not end-users?

Comment: Are you looking to have the tabs like your example and or produce the data?

Comment: Yes I mean the administrators sorry. They can add people people. The tabs in my example is the actual site and how it should look. Right now it's simply a .show() and .hide() on static id's

Comment: OK, what you need is an Admin page, which allows, *inter alia*, lawyers to be added backend. Then, your "Lawyers" page stays exactly the same as it is. Whenever is loaded/reloaded, it will include any new lawyers added via the Admin page.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have the backend worked out. The front-end is the problem. I don't know how to write the jQuery part if I dynamically generate html.

Comment: @MarcB I understand that PHP should add html in a structured way. That's why the id="" is blank right now. But I have no idea how to use that in jQuery. I'm a massive noob in jQuery.

Comment: But your HTML is *already* dynamically generated isn't it?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yeah, The PHP generates it. The jQuery is the problem. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more relevant code is the javascript in `/varlaw/js/main.js`, though it is also useful to have seen the PHP.

First, in PHP, build the lawyer buttons inside a containing div as follows :

```
<div><!-- unstyled structural div -->
    <?php foreach ($team as $lawyer) { ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $lawyer->id?>_button" class="lawyer_title_small title-<?php echo $lawyer->title_colour;?>">
        <h2><?php echo $lawyer->name?></h2>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

Second, in PHP build the "team_info" divs inside a containing div as follows :

```
<div><!-- unstyled structural div -->
    <?php foreach ($team as $lawyer) { ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $lawyer->id;?>" class="team_info">
        <div class="team_info_left">
            <img src="img/team/<?php echo $lawyer->picture;?>"/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color: #9e0039;">TEL:</th>
                    <th><?php echo $lawyer->tel;?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color: #9e0039;">GSM:</th>
                    <th><?php echo $lawyer->gsm;?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color: #9e0039;">MAIL:</th>
                    <th style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo $lawyer->mail;?></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="team_info_right">
            <h4>OVER <?php echo $lawyer->name;?></h4>
            <?php echo $lawyer->about;?>
            <h4>VOORKEURKENNIS:</h4>
            <?php echo $lawyer->knowledge;?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

You now have two *congruent* structural divs; corresponding child elements of these divs have the *same index* within their parent div. This is important as it allows for very simple, efficient javaScript.

Third, in javaScript replace all the `$("#marc_button")...`, `$("#dirk_button")...` etc. code with :

```
$(".lawyer_title_small").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("lawyer_title_main")) { //this trap may be unnecessary
        return;
    } else {
        //hide all lawyer divs, then selectively show the appropriate lawyer div
        //ie. the div with the same index as the button that was clicked
        $(".team_info").hide().eq($this.index()).show();
    }
});
```

If the trap is indeed unnecessary, then the click handler will simplify to :

```
$(".lawyer_title_small").on("click", function() {
    $(".team_info").hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Now, your PHP can build the page with as few or as many Lawyers as it likes and the javascript will handle them.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! Great snippet of code!